# Can I transfer all Mail accounts to a new Mac?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I have many email accounts in my Mail app, lets say 15. Entering the necessary values and passwords etc. for each of these is a huge pain. Is it possible to somehow "save" all of those accounts and transfer them to a new Mac, so I don't need to do it manually? This would include icloud mail, gmail, exchange, etc. accounts and passwords.

Note that in this case I am using macOS Sierra. Also note that I am referring to transferring the accounts login information and email server info to receive and send emails, and not referring to transferring actual emails.

Comment: I don't have a suitable test environment to determine exactly what is needed (and I am Mojave), but I think the account info is in ~/Library/Accounts. Passwords are in the keychain.

Comment: any reason why you do not want to use the Apple Migration assistant

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer all accounts and passwords that are saved by transferring your Keychain from your old mac to your new mac.

## Manually (long)

**On your old mac**

Go into your users Library folder which is */Library*. By default, this folder is hidden. Open your finder and press, **COMMAND+SHIFT+L**. This should jump you to that location.

Finder the folder named, *Keychain*, and copy it to a USB drive or into iCloud.

If you use a USB drive, remove it from the mac now and go to your new mac.

**On your new mac**

Insert USB drive if thats what your using. Otherwise, go into your iCloud. Select the *Keychain* directory you saved there and copy it.

Go to your users *Library* by using the same method as before and paste the *Keychain* directory. If asked, merge the folders and authenticate. You may also replace the *Keychain* directory on the new mac with your old *Keychain* documents. **This will replace any information such as logins you may have already saved on your new mac.**

## Easiest Method

Enable iCloud Keychain on your Apple ID.

Use the same Apple ID on both macs.

All login info will sync together like magic.

Comment: Sorry doesn't work any  more. None of the methods described anywhere on the Internet work any more.